# What is the way to process the data of ArrayList of 1 million HashMap objects through Kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have data in an ArrayList of 1 million HashMap objects and I want to process this data in two places by 2 Kafka topics at a time. If I start the process by sending this ArrayList in to the topic and consumed by two topics, I am getting

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError java heap space error

Is there any suggestion to solve this?

Comment: Hi sheetalsk - welcome to StackOverflow. It's generally requested here that you include the code that doesn't work, as well as an error trace that shows what is happening when you run it. Hopefully with this info, someone will be able to help you out with your issue. Good luck!

Comment: You solve it by starting with increasing your heap space like any other Java app

Comment: This is a very vague question. Are you using Kafka streams, simple prod/consumer API, what does Kafka have to do with processing? Please clarify